# What happens to reputation when I get merged?

Tags: discussion, reputation, user-accounts

A while ago I sent an email to the stackexchange team on recovering my account https://mathoverflow.net/users/21278/ben-lim. They said I should create a new account and merge it with the old one. This is now my new account.

What happens to my reputation upon merging of accounts, does it simply add? What about questions and answers?

Comment: Ben, are your accounts now merged? I had submitted a form as per your request, but they came back and asked which account was to be merged into which (this is an extra hoop that I've never had to pass through; I've handled merger requests before). Let me know if you need some help here (notify me by writing @ToddTrimble in your comment).

Comment: Dear @ToddTrimble, could you merge me with my previous account please? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The new account will get the activity of the old one in addition.

That is the old posts will be associated to the new account so that you have access to your old posts (e.g., for editing); and, you will also get the associated points (the points of the old account) in addition to the ones you have on this account. So, yes, the points simply add (in most cases or almost, see below).

Basically, it should be as if you always had had just one account.

(Side remark: strictly speaking, it should not *always* be true that the points of the merged account is the sum of the points before the merge, due to things like capping of gained points from votes at 200 per day, but by and large and especially for smaller accounts it should be the case.)

Comment: Some other weird stuff happens with self-interactions but that's also not anything to worry about.

Comment: And probably you get the association bonus only once.

Comment: It would have to be at least 1 less (+1 for beginning users)

Comment: Right, forgot about the 1 for the start (so typically 1 less than sum). But also if one has more than one account on the network it could happen one has more than the sum at the end (if association bonus kicks in after the merge).

Comment: Dear @quid, thanks for your answer. I have not been merged even after replying to Todd Trimble, what should I do next? Thanks.

Comment: @BenLim you are welcome and sorry for the belated reply. It is strange this did not yet happen. The most likely thing (this is a guess) is that the initial request was for some reason not dealt with instantly/right away as there was some need for clarification and then it got forgotten. Since they were already involved I would contact the sites moderators again. Either via another comment to Todd Trimble or via writing email to moderators'at'mathoverflow.net (An issue is comment notifications are somewhat easy to miss if one has more than one.)