# Can I be merged please?

Tags: support, status-completed, user-accounts

In a previous meta thread [here](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1405/what-happens-to-reputation-when-i-get-merged), I wrote a comment to Todd Trimble and requested to be merged with my [previous account](https://mathoverflow.net/users/21278/ben-lim) (I have lost all access to that account). I have also sent in a form requesting that I be merged, but nothing has happened. Can a moderator help to merge me please?

Thanks.

Comment: Very strange. I thought I had responded to this. If you give me the user account number into which you want your other account(s) to be merged, I will do this again. Sorry for your inconvenience. (Ah -- I *had* made this request of you before. But I assume from your current request that it's 45525.)

Answer (score 4):

All set! In the future if you're locked out, please [contact us](https://mathoverflow.net/contact) to let us know and we'll get it sorted for you.

Comment: Thank you, Tim! (I was about to write you, because for some reason the SE team hadn't responded to my second merger request form -- I thought enough time had elapsed where I would have heard something.)

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I have submitted a request form (again), asking to have your 21278 account merged into your 45525 account. Please comment below if this is not what you wanted done. I should be receiving a response from the SE team soon.